# C# DataGridView- How show horizontal scroll

Tags: c#, datagridview, scroll

I added datagridview on form. 
set property- scrollBar : Both
dynamically I add data in datagridview . 
Appears vertical scroll but horizontal isn't present.

How can i show horizontal scroll.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine. It depends if your DataGridView control has the width large enough to hold the columns you have in your data source: if it does, then no horizontal scroll will appear.

Set the width property  to a smaller value and the horizontal scroll will be present.

The same with vertical scroll. They both appear only when the control can't display the data.

Comment: It doesn't work when i set property Dock : FILL. but i need resized grid.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand exactly what you are saying: when setting the grid to dock-fill, it will take up to the whole space in the form. When resizing the form, the horizontal and/or vertical scroll bars will appear. Is there something else you want to do?